# String compare function equals not giving correct result

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse with java
I am trying to compare two string removing all the space between them.

Here is my code

First I am removing whitespace within the Strings.

```
System.out.println("["+StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(s4)+"]");
System.out.println("["+StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(s3)+"]");

// comparing Strings
if(s4.equals(s3))
{
    System.out.println("Text Match");'      
}
```

Below is the output from lines 1 and 2 that is displaying on Eclipse console:

```
[gnarlyadj.Somethingthatisgnarlyhasmanyknotsandbumpyareasonitssurface.nudosoadj.Algonudosotienemuchosnudosyunasuperficiellenadebultos.]
[gnarlyadj.Somethingthatisgnarlyhasmanyknotsandbumpyareasonitssurface.nudosoadj.Algonudosotienemuchosnudosyunasuperficiellenadebultos.]
```

From what I can see, there is no difference between two string yet it is displaying string as a mismatch.

Comment: Strings in Java are *immutable*. Any operation that involves "changing" a `String` ... doesn't. It returns a new `String`

Answer (score 12):

You did not assign the results of the `deleteWhitespace()` operation to anything. Your two strings will therefore remain unchanged.

Store the result like so, before printing it:

`s4 = StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(s4);`

Comment: After doing this when i execute the program again its still showing some spaces.   For example look at this output  -   reminiscev.Whenyoureminisce,yourememberpastexperiencesorevents.rememorar v.Cuandorememoras,recuerdasexperienciasosucesospasados.                Here you can see single space is still displaying befroe "v" in 2nd line 2nd word. I am not getting why this space is still displaying.

Comment: @user3270693 Without seeing more of your code, I can't tell what's going on. If you post more code, please leave a comment here so I'll know to come back and look. Don't post ALL of your code - we only need the relevant pieces.

Answer (score 1):

The method StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(s4) does not change the String referenced by s4 ([Strings are immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Java)) but returns a new string.

If you do the following code:

```
s3 = StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(s3);
s4 = StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(s4);

if (s4.equals(s3)) {
    System.out.println("Text Match");'      
}
```

Then you will see that the two strings are really equal and the "Text Match" is printed.

Comment: It is not printing Text Match.  After doing this when i execute the program again its still showing some spaces. For example look at this output - reminiscev.Whenyoureminisce,yourememberpastexperiencesorevents.rememorar v.Cuand‌​orememoras,recuerdasexperienciasosucesospasados. Here you can see single space is still displaying befroe "v" in 2nd line 2nd word. I am not getting why this space is still displaying.

Comment: Are you printing the string after that you are deleting white spaces?

<pre> <code>
    String s3 = "String With Spaces";
    s3 = StringUtils.deleteWhitespace();
    System.out.println(s3);
</pre> </code>

This code should remove all white spaces from the string.

Other thing to check, what is it StringUtils?
I supposed it was the library method of org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils. Am I correct?
If not then you have to check if the StringUtils implementation really works.

Comment: yes is is in org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils. I am using it for my string and printing it and there i can still see the space.